# How do I get cywgin's remove file command to prompt a warning when I try to delete a file?

Tags: cygwin, rm

Whenever I use `rm` to remove files in my Cygwin terminal, the file gets deleted without any warning. This is particularly annoying when I try to remove multiple files with the wildcard and some other characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Cygwin is Linux shell running inside the Windows OS, you can try something similar to what you would do in actual Linux.  Open your `.bashrc` file in the Vim editor:

```
vi ~/.bashrc
```

Add the following line at the end of the file

```
alias rm=’rm –I’
```

This tells Cygwin to run the command `rm` as `rm -I`, which is remove in information mode.  This will generate the warning prompt each time you try to `rm` a file.

You might also want to change the settings for the root user, and possibly other users.  Have a look at [this useful article](http://www.howtogeek.com/183690/enable-the-confirmation-when-deleting-files-and-folders-using-the-rm-command-in-ubuntu/) for more information.